# Deleting IWTreeViewItems causes exception on form release

Tags: delphi, delphi-2006, intraweb

On my form I have a IWTreeView and two buttons. One button deletes some IWTreeViewItems, the other releases the form:

```
procedure TIWForm1.IWButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  IWTreeView1.Items[0].Subitems.Clear;
end;

procedure TIWForm1.IWButton2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Release;
end;
```

Releasing the form after deleting the IWTreeViewItems causes an exception:

> Error message raised by the
>   application:   Access violation at
>   address 004E0D8A in module
>   'TryTree.exe'. Read of address
>   00000000

When there is another form active and the application is not terminated by this form release, the error message is:

> Error message raised by the
>   application:   List index out of
>   bounds (-1)

Using IntraWeb 9.0.42 (because of TMS controls and Delphi 2006, as TMS has not tested with 10.0.17 and delphi 2006).

I tried to IWTreeView1.ClearAll in the form destroy, which did not help at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of SubItems.Clear I now use

```
for i := IWTreeView1.Items[0].SubItems.Count-1 downto 0 do begin
    TIWTreeViewItem(IWTreeView1.Items[0].SubItems[i]).Free;
end;
```

This works. Still open for better solutions, maybe not involving a loop through all subitems.